# Assigning 5 different variables from 1 single function

Tags: python

I have function **scoring** that I have to use to create 5 variables, which are randomly selected with integers, with **scores1** being the first variable.  I want to be able to assign new variables *scores2*, *scores3*, *scores4*, and *scores5*, which all follow the same path as **scores1**.  The code below does not have errors; it is just an example of what I am trying to explain.  How can you use or edit this function to create these 5 random integer variables?

```
import simplegui

import random

A_plus = 3
A = 3
B = 36
C = 58

def scoring():
    global scores

    score = random.randint(1, 100)
    if score < 4:

        scores = ['97', '98', '99', '100']
        scores1 = random.choice(scores)


    if 3 < score < 7:

        scores = ['93','94','95','96'] 
        scores1 = random.choice(scores)


    if 6 < score < 45:

        scores = ['83','86','87','89']
        scores1 = random.choice(scores)


    if 44 < score < 101:

        scores = ['70','72','76','79']
        scores1 = random.choice(scores)


scoring()
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use a list?

Comment: what do you mean? sorry im not good at python

Comment: what do you mean by "which all follow the same path"?

Comment: they can all assigned the same way the variable scores1 was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight-forward approach is to make the assignments outside of the function.  Then it is easy to put the results in any required variable:

```
def scoring():
    score = random.randint(1, 100)
    if score < 4:
        scores = ['97', '98', '99', '100']
        score = random.choice(scores)
    if 3 < score < 7:
        scores = ['93','94','95','96'] 
        score = random.choice(scores)
    if 6 < score < 45:
        scores = ['83','86','87','89']
        score = random.choice(scores)
    if 44 < score < 101:
        scores = ['70','72','76','79']
        score = random.choice(scores)
    return score

score1 = scoring()
score2 = scoring()
score3 = scoring()
score4 = scoring()
score5 = scoring()
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you are trying to do, but below code will do the work for you

```
import random

A_plus = 3
A = 3
B = 36
C = 58

def scoring():
    global scores

    score = random.randint(1, 100)
    if score < 4:

        scores = ['97', '98', '99', '100']
        scores1 = random.choice(scores)


    if 3 < score < 7:

        scores = ['93','94','95','96'] 
        scores1 = random.choice(scores)


    if 6 < score < 45:

        scores = ['83','86','87','89']
        scores1 = random.choice(scores)


    if 44 < score < 101:

        scores = ['70','72','76','79']
        scores1 = random.choice(scores)

    return scores1
score_list = []
for each in range(5):
    score_list.append(scoring())
print score_list
```

`output : ['87', '79', '79', '89', '86']`

You just need to bind it to a variable. Its up to you, you can put it in a list or a dictionary or individual variables

Comment: i need it assigned to a variable not just printed out

Comment: I just edited my post you can check it, here i'm using a list to store the scores from the function.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you want:

```
import random

def scoring(score):
    if 0 <= score < 4:
        scores = ['97', '98', '99', '100']
        return random.choice(scores)
    elif 4 <= score < 7:
        scores = ['93','94','95','96'] 
        return random.choice(scores)
    elif 7 <= score < 45:
        scores = ['83','86','87','89']
        return random.choice(scores)
    elif 45 <= score <= 100:
        scores = ['70','72','76','79']
        return random.choice(scores)

l = [3, 3, 57, 70, 99] # these are the list of variables
scores = [scoring(score) for score in l]
print(scores)
```

Output:

```
['100', '97', '89', '72']
```

Since the output is randomised, the output above is for your reference.

Comment: this is good, but 1. I need 5 outputs   2. Where are the variables?

Comment: @JohnnyAppleseed I have updated the code. Put in the values you want in list `l` for needed.